# Rails 5: multipart field inside a nested form doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using the `carrierwave gem` in order to upload files. I have a form with one `nested_form field` from where I'm trying to upload multiple files. But for some odd reason the `multipart=true` doesn't work when I try to upload multiple files. I get this error: `Validation failed: Attachments media files can't be blank` and in the console I get an `Unpermitted parameter: :media_files`....even thought the params seem to pass when the form is submitted:

```
Started POST "/item/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-23 13:08:19 +0300
Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>
"tDpyPV9fPxLUHgRVb4G6P3eMLFUv0hKVnNPJCAcgYISCwjIbjA5bu/iXOy0k6yL
8+QWXs3MyoJ3lzzyhj3rqkw==", "item"=>{"title"=>"Sample",  "description"
=>"Lorem", "attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"media_files"=>[#
<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe818a5ecb0 @tempfile=# 
<Tempfile:/var/folders/hq/pr4rt14n7s31v3f6292wtjm00000gn/T/
RackMultipart20181023-1573-1r65sf9.jpg>, @original_filename=
"image1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content- 
Disposition: form-data; name=\"item[attachments_attributes]
[0][media_files][]\"; filename=\"image1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: 
image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile
:0x007fe818a5ebe8 @tempfile=#
<Tempfile:/var/folders/hq/pr4rt14n7s31v3f6292wtjm00000gn
/T/RackMultipart20181023-1573-1lbr709.jpg>,  
@original_filename="image2.jpg", @content_type=
"image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;  
name=\"item[attachments_attributes][0][media_files][]\";  
filename=\"image2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">], "item_id"=>"# 
<Item:0x007fe813ef65e8>"}}}, "commit"=>"Create"}

Unpermitted parameter: :media_files
```

This is nested_form setup I have:

```
  create_table "attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "item_id"
  t.string "media_files"
  t.string "content_type"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true
end

class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  mount_uploader :media_files, AttachmentUploader
  validates_presence_of :media_files
end
```

This is the `attachments_controller.rb` method:

```
def create
  params["item"]["attachments_attributes"]["0"]["media_files"].each { |file| @attachment = Attachment.new(:media_files => file)}

  respond_to do |format|
    if @attachment.save
      format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, notice: 'Attachment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :'shows/show', status: :created, location: @attachment }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and the nested params inside the `items_controller.rb`:

```
params.require(:item).permit(:title, :description, attachments_attributes: [:media_files, :item_id, :content_type])
```

The form with the nested field:

```
<%= form_for(@item, url: items_create_path, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |form| %>
<%= form.text_field :title, id: :item_title, autofocus: true, :class=>"form-control" %>
    <%= form.text_area :description, id: :item_description, :class=>"form-control" %>

  <%= form.fields_for :attachments do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.file_field :media_files, multiple: true, :id=>"upload-photo" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.submit "Create", :class=>"btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

> Unpermitted parameter: :media_files

Means the parameter "media_files", which you use in the following line has not been permitted:

```
params["item"]["attachments_attributes"]["0"]["media_files"].each { |file| @attachment = Attachment.new(:media_files => file)}
```

This line itself is quite strange, as you're iterating on the parameters to instantiate a new Attachment each time oO

This line is almost OK, just change the `attachments_attributes`:

```
params.require(:item).permit(:title, :description, attachments_attributes: [:item_id, :content_type, :media_files => []])
```

But that's what you have to give to `Item.new`, as your form points to `items_create_path`.

Why do you expect it to reach attachments_controller.rb ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Geoffroy. Well from my understanding the nested form `<%= form.fields_for :attachments do |f| %>` is suppose to point to the create method in the `attachments_controller`? Unless I'm wrong.

Comment: My goal is it to create the item and multiple attachments from the items_create_path nested form. I hope this helps you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Also if I delete the `multiple: true` from the field it works... but I can only add one file `<%= f.file_field :media_files, multiple: true, :id=>"upload-photo" %>`

Comment: @Theopap no you're wrong, the fields for has nothing to do with attachments controller as your request is "Process[ed] by ItemsController#create"

Comment: I see what you're saying about the `ItemsController#create` ... but I still can't understand why its returning a `Unpermitted parameter: :media_files` since I have the nested params setup inside the items controller correctly. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Theopap I updated my answer, didn't see this one ;-) to permit an array you have to permit `:media_files => []` at the end

Comment: I changed the params to this `:media_files => []` but I'm getting this error: `no implicit conversion of nil into String`